# if camapaign status is completed , then add campaign actual cost to account custom field(Total Campaign Cost)

Tags: trigger

Each time a campaign status marked as completed add the campaign actual cost amount to account custom field Total Campaign cost...create a lookup on campaign of account

Comment: I suggest to do the basic Trailhead module on Triggers https://trailhead.salesforce.com/de/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers and look through the trigger best practices: e.g. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000DBl8IAG

Answer (score 1):

The best way of achieving this is through a trigger - you can interact with multiple objects in doing this. The filter logic would be rather simple, the question you need to ask yourself is can an Account have multiple Campaigns? And if so, would you just like the 'Total Campaign Cost' to be overwritten each time a campaign is set to completed for that Account?

Comment: if account has multiple campaign and then we want to sum all campaign actual cost and then add this sum in Total Campaign Cost....can you please tell me code